# APA 7th query on journal titles

Tags: citations

In the APA [style guide](https://columbiacollege-ca.libguides.com/apa/journalarticle), it states:

> Capitalize only the first letter of the first word of the article title. If there is a colon in the article title, also capitalize the first letter of the first word after the colon.

So just to be clear, if the article title is "Sentiment Analysis of US Airline Twitter Data using New Adaboost Approach", do I downcase it myself and cite it as

> Eswaran, P., Santhosh, M., Krishnan, A. H., & Kumar, T. (2019, April). Sentiment analysis of US airline twitter data using new adaboost approach. International Journal of Engineering Research & Technology (IJERT), 7, 1–3.

Comment: Yes, that is what the style guide says.

Comment: Well, I don't know about "Adaboost," but Twitter should remain capitalized.